# Convert string to DateTime with format "dd/MM/yyyy"

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string that is a date in the format of "MMddyyyy". I need to convert it to a DateTime with formatting "dd/MM/yyyy". I created the following code, but I keep getting a Format Exception. Parse, ParseExact, TryParseExact all give a Format Exception also.

```
string dater = "10312016";
DateTime condate = Convert.ToDateTime(dater);
```

I have tried the following:

```
string dater = "10312016";
        DateTime condate =  DateTime.ParseExact(dater, "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime condate2 = DateTime.ParseExact(dater, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

condate works, but it is in the wrong format. It needs to be "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Sorry for not including that.I am using C#.

Comment: Just a side note - `DateTime` does not have formatting. You can convert a `DateTime` to a `string` with a particular format, but `DateTime` is just a numeric value.

Answer (score -1):

string dater = "10312016";
DateTime condate = Convert.ToDateTime(dater).tostring("dd/MM/yyyy");

Just try this. I am posting answer from my mobile. So tostring syntax may not right. When u type tostring in IDE then it will be alright.

### Edit

sorry for later answer. see this code and it is working.

```
            string dater = "10312016";
            DateTime condate = DateTime.ParseExact(dater, "MMddyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string strDate = condate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Th
```

anks

Comment: This is completely wrong.

Comment: @Mou....I get an error stating that Canno implicitly convert string to DateTime